# Why my attempt to define a natural type with typedef doesn't work?

Tags: c, gcc, typedef

I tried to define a 'natural' type, like that:

```
typedef unsigned int nat;
```

But if I define a nat variable, that variable behaves like an ordinary int:

```
nat natural_index;
natural_index = 10; // That's what I want. 
natural_index = -10; // Still a valid option.
```

In resume, I wanted to know why the compiler does not show a message, like
"-10 is not a unsigned int", and what could I do to define a 'natural' type.

**extra information**: I "printf" the variable natural_index, and the value '-10' was printed. I expected at least, another positive number (not exactly 10).

Comment: You may be able to increase compiler warning levels to see a diagnostic. On gcc you can use `-Wconversion` to see: `warning: negative integer implicitly converted to unsigned type [-Wsign-conversion]  x = -10;`

Comment: Great! This message really showed up by here (and some another ones)! An excellent tip! Thanks @DavidBowling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C doesn't support what you are trying to do, on two different levels.

First, a `typedef` in C does not create a new, distinct type; it just creates a shorthand name for the original type.  Thus, after

```
typedef unsigned int nat;
```

the declaration

```
nat natural_index;
```

is 100% equivalent to

```
unsigned int natural_index;
```

(What's the point of `typedef`, then?  It's most useful when the "underlying type" might differ based on the target architecture; for instance, the standard typedef `uint64_t` might be shorthand for `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` depending on the architecture.)

Second, C has no mechanism for changing whether or not arithmetic expressions perform *implicit conversions*.  In

```
natural_index = -10;
```

the assignment operator will convert the negative number `-10` (with type `int`) to a large unsigned number (namely `(UINT_MAX - 10) + 1`, which is probably, but not necessarily, 4,294,967,286) in the process, and there is no way to disable that.

Your options are to work in a language that actually supports this kind of thing (e.g. Ada, Haskell, ML) or to write a "linting" program that parses C itself and enforces whatever rules you want it to enforce (existing examples are `lint` and `sparse`).

Comment: Great, @zwol! This was very well explained! But  there still have an issue in your second argument, because I print the variable 'natural_index' and the value `-10` is printed. And I make some operations like: `natural_index - 1`, and the result is `-11`.

Comment: I was printing with the `%d` argument instead `%u`. But I found interesting this conversion with `printf`.

Comment: @Vytor Yes, it's completely up to you to make your `printf` format specification match the arguments.  Your compiler may or may not have a mode in which it will warn you if they don't match, but that's as helpful as C gets.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to separate the expression-statements with semicolon `;`.

```
natural_index = 10;
natural_index = -10;
```

`-10` to a large signed number during the evaluation of assignment operator `=`.

`6.5.16.1p2` (Simple assignment) from ISO9899 says:

> In simple assignment (=), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression.

When you use the storage class specifier `typedef`, this tells the parser to add an alias identifier `nat` for the type `unsigned int` in the environment of the parser or in the parse tree that it outputs.  In this case `nat` will be evaluated to a type in declarations, so when you declare the object with identifier `natural_index`, the left-value associated with this object will have the type `unsigned int`.

Comment: Thanks @alinsoar! But the code written above, was a simple sample.In real code I didn't forget the semicolon :). My problem was that when I compile and print the variable natural_index, the value printed was '-10' and I expected at least a non negative number, or some error.